# Inserting Rows into an Empty Pandas DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty data frame created like so:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

What I want to do, is insert a record so that it looks like this:

```
     a     b     c
0    1     1     2
```

Is there a command for this? My search didn't seem to help me out much.

Comment: `df_test.append([{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}])`